# What is better: creating two retrofit interfaces for rest api with different base url or creating one and dynamically pass url everytime?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

Which approach is better? Creating two retrofit interfaces for rest api with different base url or creating one and dynamically pass url everytime?

Comment: Either can be fine depending on how you use it. I myself tend to create a Retrofit instance for every URL.